# Error: XML declaration should precede all document content

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I am getting this error suddenly as the title says.. I am stuck.. What's the meaning of this error and are there any possible solutions there?
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Edit_Text_1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:hint="@string/Edit_Text_1_Hint"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500">
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Edit_Text_2"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:hint="@string/Edit_Text_2_Hint"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500">
</EditText>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There may be at most one XML declaration in an XML document, and if present, it must appear at the very top of the document -- no visible or invisible characters are allowed to be before it.  See duplicate link for further details.

Comment: thanks,there was a space before <?xml....

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to upvote the question and answer at the duplicate link to show they helped.  (You now have voting privileges as you've reached 15 rep.)